# Converting a list to an array when list has quotes and embedded comma

Tags: javascript, array, coldfusion

This function converts a list to an array when list has quotes and embedded comma:

```
array function convertRow(required string lstRow) {

    var arResult = [];
    var arTemp = ListToArray(arguments.lstRow, ',', true);

    var quoteMode = false;
    var startQuote = false;

    for (var i in arTemp) {

        if (i CONTAINS '"' && not quoteMode) { startQuote =  true; }

        if (startQuote) {
            ArrayAppend(arResult, replace(i, '"', ''));

            startQuote = false;
            quoteMode = true;
        }
        else if (quoteMode) {
            arResult[ArrayLen(arResult)] &= "," & replace(i, '"', '');

            if (i CONTAINS '"') quoteMode = false;
        }
        else
            ArrayAppend(arResult, i);
    }

    writedump(lstRow);
    writedump(arResult);

    return arResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get rid of your startQuote variable, I reduced the number of `i CONTAINS '"'` comparasions by 1.

```
array function convertRow(required string lstRow) {
    var arResult = [];
    var arTemp = ListToArray(arguments.lstRow, ',', true);
    var quoteMode = false;

    for (var i in arTemp) {
        var containsQuote = i CONTAINS '"';
        if (containsQuote && not quoteMode) {
            ArrayAppend(arResult, replace(i, '"', ''));
            quoteMode = true;
        }
        else if (quoteMode){
            arResult[ArrayLen(arResult)] &= "," & replace(i, '"', '');
            quoteMode = not containsQuote;
        }
        else{
            ArrayAppend(arResult, i);
        }
    }


    writedump(lstRow);
    writedump(arResult);

    return arResult;
}
```